# Django ORM error - cannot insert NULL into Primary Key

Tags: python-3.x, django

When I'm trying to create an object using **Django** **ORM**, **Oracle** database asks me for the **Primary** **Key**, which corresponds to `id_orden` field in my **Orden** model, which I have defined as `IntegerField(primary key=True)`.
But **Django** **ORM** is supposed to insert the next value into the database as I have defined the **Primary** **Key** field, so I don't understand why I'm still being asked to provide it and why it's still empty.

**The error I'm getting**:

> IntegrityError at /listado_carro/ ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into
> ("SUSHIFU"."MTV_ORDEN"."ID_ORDEN")

**The error occurs is in this line in views.py**:

```
orden 
=Orden.objects.create(id_carro=carro,fecha_hora=timezone.now(),nombre_cliente=usuario2.nombre+' 
'+usuario2.apellido,direccion=usuario2.direccion,nota='',total=total2)
```

**Models.py**

```
class Orden(models.Model):
    id_orden = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    id_carro = models.OneToOneField('Carro', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_hora = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    nombre_cliente = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=99)
    nota = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    total= models.IntegerField(default='0')
```

**Views.py**

```
def listado_carro(request):
    usuario = request.user
    usuario2 = Usuario.objects.get(id=usuario.id)
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
    carros = Carro.objects.filter(id_carro=usuario.id)
    carro = Carro.objects.filter(id_carro=usuario.id).first()    
    total = locale.format('%.0f',
                  Carro.objects.filter(id_carro=usuario.id).aggregate(sum=Sum('precio_producto'))['sum'], 
                                                                           grouping=True, monetary=True)
    total2 = Carro.objects.filter(id_carro=usuario.id).aggregate(sum=Sum('precio_producto'))['sum']
    orden =Orden.objects.create(id_carro=carro,fecha_hora=timezone.now(),
                            nombre_cliente=usuario2.nombre+' '+usuario2.apellido,
                            direccion=usuario2.direccion,nota='',
                            total=total2)
    data = {'carros':carros,'total':total, 'orden':orden}
    return render(request, "listado_carro.html", data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined your primary key as an *integer field*, which means you **must** supply an id with insert statements.  Instead you should use an **[`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#autofield)**:

```
class Orden(models.Model):
    id_orden = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_carro = models.OneToOneField('Carro', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks you, in orden to get work correctly, i have to drop all the tables on my oracle database, and then make the makemigrations and migrate, dont work with just makemigrations and migrate.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the Django ORM to automatically increment the field, you'll need to use `AutoField` or `BigAutoField` instead of `IntegerField`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#autofield

Try:

```py
class Orden(models.Model):
    id_orden = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_carro = models.OneToOneField('Carro', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_hora = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    nombre_cliente = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=99)
    nota = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    total= models.IntegerField(default='0')
```

Good luck!